# Implement List in Point Chart Flutter

Tags: arrays, list, charts, flutter, point

Can you tell the difference of this code:

```
final installmentList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < installment.length; i++) {
    installmentList.add(new LinearStatistic(i, installment[i].count));
}
```

from this code:

```
final data = [
    new LinearStatistic(0, 5),
    new LinearStatistic(1, 25),
    new LinearStatistic(2, 100),
    new LinearStatistic(3, 75),
];
```

When I debug and use the 'data' variable, the return statement is called, but when I use the  'instalmentList' variable, it's not getting called.

```
return [
    new charts.Series<LinearStatistic, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearStatistic sales, _) => sales.position,
        measureFn: (LinearStatistic sales, _) => sales.count,
        data: data,
        )
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
// final data = [
//   new LinearSales(0, 5),
//   new LinearSales(1, 25),
//   new LinearSales(2, 100),
//   new LinearSales(3, 75),
// ];
List installment = [5, 10, 4, 22, 12];
final List installmentList = <LinearSales>[];
for (var i = 0; i < installment.length; i++) {
  installmentList.add(new LinearSales(i, installment[i]));
}
return [
  new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
    id: 'Sales',
    colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
    domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
    measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
    data: installmentList,
  )
];}
```

Use this code as reference this is the change I did `final List installmentList = <LinearSales>[];`

[image: Here is the Result]

Comment: I did, but the return still skipped away in debug :(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/212SuSPS when I use instalmentList the error was 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<LinearStatistic>' thanks

Comment: @VanyaRachel I edited the above code, Now see. I have changed this: final List installmentList = <LinearSales>[];

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
final installmentList = [new LinearStatistic(0, 0)];
```

for declare the array. thanks guys